# Android FileBody equivalent encoding in iOS

Tags: android, ios, afnetworking, multipartform-data, androidhttpclient

We have some code posting an image and some other data as part of a Multipart in a POST request. In Android is working just fine, but I can't seem to make it work on iOS, where I keep getting a 500 Internal Server Error. The working Android code looks like

```java
String uploadURL = "http://someServer.com/upload";
String imageToUploadPath = "imgFilePath";// path de la imagen a subir
String userId = "123";
String token = "abcd";

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uploadURL);
File f = new File(imageToUploadPath);
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(f);
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
Charset chars = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
reqEntity.addPart("id", new StringBody(userId, chars));
reqEntity.addPart("token", new StringBody(token, chars));
reqEntity.addPart("image", fileBody);
httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
```

My iOS attempt using AFNetworking is as follows

```objc
uploadURLStr = @"http://someServer.com/upload";
NSString *token = @"abcd";
NSString *userID = @"123";

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
NSMutableSet *supportedContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes mutableCopy];
supportedContentTypes addObject:@"text/html"];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = supportedContentTypes;
NSURLSessionTask *task = [manager POST:uploadURLStr
                            parameters:nil
                   constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
                         NSDictionary *tokenHeaders = @{@"Content-Disposition": @"form-data",
                                                        @"name": @"token",
                                                        @"Content-Type": @"text/plain",
                                                        @"charset": @"ISO-8859-1",
                                                        @"Content-Transfer-Encoding": @"8bit"
                                                        };
                         [formData appendPartWithHeaders:tokenHeaders body:[token dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]];
                         NSMutableDictionary *userIDHeaders = [tokenHeaders mutableCopy];
                         [userIDHeaders setObject:@"id" forKey:@"name"];
                         [formData appendPartWithHeaders:[userIDHeaders copy] body:[userID dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]];

                         NSDictionary *imgHeaders = @{@"Content-Disposition": @"form-data",
                                                      @"name": @"image",
                                                      @"filename": fileName,
                                                      @"Content-Type": @"application/octet-stream",
                                                      @"Content-Transfer-Encoding": @"binary"
                                                      };
                         [formData appendPartWithHeaders:imgHeaders
                                                    body:[imgData base64EncodedDataWithOptions:0]];
                    }
                                      progress:^(NSProgress *uploadProgress) {
                                          NSLog(@"progress: %.2f", uploadProgress.fractionCompleted);
                                      }
                                       success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
                                           NSLog(@"responseObject = %@", responseObject);
                                       } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, NSError *error) {
                                           [self showUploadError];
                                           NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
        }];
```

Headers for each part we managed to log it from the Android app so we replicated it -for instance, I was sending the image with a **Content-Type** of *image/jpeg* and Android sends it as *application/octet-stream*- I assume that the image data is not being encoded as in Android. I have tried with base64 encoding as it's in the code now -tried different options other than 0-, just leaving the NSData returned by UIImageJPEG representation but I can't hit the nail. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you check your server log. Server  will give you the exact problem of 500:- Internal server error.

Comment: I'm trying to get access to it; it's a project hosted on Google Cloud Platform but when trying to login Google asks to confirm through a phone number to which we do not have access currently

Comment: actually some times this type of  issue come. I have also faced  some issue (working in android but not in IOS).